# How do I get Specific user information through google, Facebook and twitter sign up?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

for my app for android and iOS, I using Firebase Authentication with Google, Facebook and Twitter Sign In.
While using the above method , I want to make sure that I get the users' information as per the following

1. Name
2. Email
3. Password
4. Date of Birth
5. Gender
6. Country

Kindly guide me what all information could be profiled in my app after using Firebase Auth for google , Facebook and twitter sign in

Comment: Hello ramneed. For us to help you, try to be more specific on what you are trying to achieve, post example code of what you have already tried and show us the errors you are seeing. BR

Comment: I am searching credentials that would be accessible after user sign in through above methods in my app, and the list above is essential for the user profile, and use these thing to show the profile of the user , like DOB, gender, country

Comment: I guess you would have the check each of the API's documentation and see what data is available from each. I know FB can be really annoying when letting apps gather user information, like, you have to specify to them why you gathering this info. The others I don't really know.

Comment: alright thanks for the guidance, I will check each and everyone's APIs docs , what all information they provide about the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase only exposes the user's display name, and email address, and even then only if those have been set in the profile of the user on the provider they sign in with. Their password is only ever exposed to Firebase if they use email+password to sign in, and even then it is not stored in plaintext in Firebase.

For date of birth, gender and country (and some of the other properties too), you will have to request them in your application code and store them somewhere. Typically developers use the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore for this.

For more on this, see:

- [Firebase: setting additional user properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties)
- [Add Extra Details on Firebase User Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038611/add-extra-details-on-firebase-user-table)
- [Adding Custom Attributes to Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825520/adding-custom-attributes-to-firebase-auth)
- [Firebase - Adding additional user data to separate DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286442/firebase-adding-additional-user-data-to-separate-db)
- [Add extra User Information with firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076988/add-extra-user-information-with-firebase)
- [How to add additional information to firebase.auth()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926672/how-to-add-additional-information-to-firebase-auth)

Comment: thank you for assistance,  I  will follow all the guides